# Is Integration by part always true?

Tags: calculus, integration

I have $\int e^x * e^{-x}dx$=$- e^x *e^{-x} +\int e^x*e^{-x} dx$ by integration by part. Which become $\int 1 = -1 +\int 1$ $\to$ $0=-1$. And the same integration but change $U=e^{-x} $ and $dv=e^x$ which yield $\int1dx=1/2 $.

Comment: Keep in mind that $\int f \, dx$ is the set of all antiderivatives of $f$. The integration by parts formula for indefinite integrals must be interpreted carefully. It tells us that $-\int u v’ \, dx + uv $ is the set of all antiderivatives of $u’ v$ (under certain mild assumptions about $u$ and $v$). Personally, I prefer to avoid indefinite integral notation entirely.

Comment: It is always true. It comes from the product rule.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your integral is indefinite, its result is computed up to constant, so that you have
$$
\int e^x e^{-x} \mathrm{d}x = \int \mathrm{d}x = x + c
$$
and
$$
- e^x e^{-x} + \int e^x e^{-x} \mathrm{d}x = x - 1 + c' = x + c
$$
setting $c=c'-1$. If you consider definite integral instead, note that the boundary term is
$$
\left[- e^x e^{-x}\right]_a^b = \left[-1\right]_a^b = -1+1 = 0 \neq -1
$$

Answer (score 0):

There's no contradiction. One choice gives the indefinite integral as  $-1+x+C$; the other choice gives the indefinite integral as $1+x+K.$